# Can't read line from cmd

Tags: c#, process, system.diagnostics

Why i can't read lines from existing cmd?

My error: "StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet."

My code:

```
 static string[] pidList;
ProcessStartInfo batFile = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", String.Format(
             "/C start /MIN {0}.bat ", numEmulator));
            batFile.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            batFile.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            batFile.RedirectStandardError = true;

            Process launchBat = new Process();
            launchBat.StartInfo = batFile;
            launchBat.Start();
            launchBat.WaitForExit();

            //get Pid
            ...
            pidList[numEmulator] = pid;

for (int i = 0; i < pidList.Length; i++)
                {
                    Process procEm = Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(pidList[i]));
                    Console.WriteLine(procEm.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: ...because stdout hasn't been redirected...? You've redirected the output for `cmd.exe`, that's it.

Comment: I'm really confused why you're using `cmd.exe /C start /MIN` - what is the benefit over just running `{0}.bat` directly?

Comment: @Liama how can i do it?

Comment: Personally, I would simplify the code to launch `{0}.bat` directly and get rid of the two separate command prompt instances you require at present.